# Invalid memory access of location 0x0 in native call by using JNI (on Mac)

Tags: java, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, native

I have two eclipse plugins calling one native framework indirectly: plugin A load libA.jnilib, plug B load libB.jnilib, then both libA.jnilib and libB.jnilib dynamically
load the same framework and call the functions in it.

pluginA or pluginB can work well separately but when they are running at the same time, pluginB will crash at framework call with the error - "Invalid memory access of location 0x0 " .(in native codes, I can find the function pointer resolve from the framework is not NULL, but failed once call it) We need the two plugin work together but we have no rights to change the codes of pluginA since it is legacy codes. So my question is technically is there any ways I could make the pluginB call the framework successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe copy the library file to another name and use that one in B.

Comment: That is exactly my first thought. But even if I change the x.framework to y.framework, the problem is still there.

Comment: I don't think that will work.  When you load a native library, you bind to the symbols in the library.

Comment: What's more, in the same scenario, the two plugins work well on win. Duplicate the dll native lib and load it in its own plugin, both dlls will be loaded into memory and native call through jni is successful